# Error when running npx create-react-app myapp on fresh install of node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**I followed the reactjs.org website for create-react-app to a T**

I haven't been able to find this specific error anywhere, and most posts are years old; *irrelevant to the specific error in the post anyways.*

Has anyone had this happen and what did you do to fix it?

Latest version of Win10 if that helps.
The LTS version v16.14.0 of Node.js

My Node.js installation is just a clean *express* installation on the OS drive. Any ideas?

The error message is below as-is after runnning `npx create-react-app my-app`:

```
C:\Users\Keith & Vanny>npx create-react-app myapp
'Vanny\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as 
an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\create-react-app\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Update: I installed it locally through `npm i create-react-app` and tried to create with `npm init react-app my-app`.

They both yield the same error above. I think it has something to do with that *unrecognized command* part of the error where a batch script was ran and it failed to parse and do the job, and then the package didn't get installed. So the javascript jargon is telling me I'm missing required packages; my `path`s for Node are perfect. *Clean install and clean of any packages.* This's got me stumped. *Looks like I'm going to the devs if we can't figure this out.*

Comment: what is the version of your node ?

Comment: @HritikSharma The LTS version v16.14.0

Comment: I'd double check that you don't inadvertently have `create-react-app` installed. [The CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) have instructions for checking that.

Comment: @ReedDunkle This node was installed on a machine that has previously no installs of node itself. According to reactjs site you don't even need to install the package via npm. The one-liner npx command does all that on the fly. I don't have a *npm install create-react-app* on the machine whatsoever.

Comment: @KeithCronin Yeah, they want you to double check that you didn't have it installed because `npx` handles it. Sounds like that's not the issue, though. I don't have any other ideas, unfortunately.

Comment: @ReedDunkle it has to be something along the lines of some broken batch script that runs after this command. You'd think this would be a fairly obvious bug. I'm surprised the first time I pick up React it's been a nightmare getting it to work or install. ```Create-react-app``` is what I need for my use-case anyways besides just learning React.

Comment: @KeithCronin You could try installing CRA instead of using npx: `npm i -g create-react-app`, then `create-react-app my-app` to scaffold the project. Even though it isn't recommended, it's acceptable and it may fix the issue.

Comment: @ReedDunkle I might try it if it comes with no performance costs. This app needs every optimization it can have respectfully to the use-case. If I could open the scripts that run when you run the command I could try and trace the culprit batch file. It could even be a ``path`` issue. So let me check at that too. Checked the ``path``s and they're perfect on Node's side.

Comment: So when installing ``create-react-app`` globally and then attempting to do ```npm init react-app my-app``` to create it. Both installed individually and tested individually locally or globally it yielded the same exact error message we have in the original post. So weird @ReedDunkle

Comment: @KeithCronin There's no performance cost. `npx` ensures that you're getting the latest version of CRA when you're scaffolding a new project, rather than needing to first update CRA and then scaffold a new project. Once you have CRA installed globally, you'll want to use `create-react-app my-app` to scaffold a new project. (That will take care of the `npm init` stuff for you along the way.)

Comment: @ReedDunkle finally.. finally fixed it. Full solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a local admin account that's just a single string with no symbols or spaces, logging into that account, and then running the npx command worked perfectly.

Installing ReactJs on a Windows machine with a users/ path that contains symbols and spaces, particulary symbols, causes a bug to happen in which npx/npm or even create-react-app can't properly parse the path to the module, therefore throwing a can't find module error.

Lesson learned: never put symbols in your windows username. Pretty bummed I have to develop on the local account for sure though.

***Update: Because I refuse to use a dummy admin account to develop on I found the perfect solution working on Win 10 Home in 2022 perfectly fine. Just create a system restore point before you do it. Here's the link! [StackExchange solution for properly renaming a faulty conflicting system username. Use the second solution, not the accepted answer.](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10?answertab=votes#tab-top)***

Just be prepared to spend some hours editing your registry.

[Direct link to the solution I'm talking about.](https://superuser.com/a/1346983/1666737)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:
npx create-react-app@latest myapp